# Prism ModuleDependency

Tags: wpf, prism

I am developing an application using prism, and in that application I can classes of module. I then have other modules that need to consume this class of module. The problem I am having is that my consumer module is getting initialized before the class of module it needs is, so the type-registration does not exist in the UnityContainer yet.

I have found this article [Module dependencies in InitializeShell with Prism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203866/module-dependencies-in-initializeshell-with-prism) which suggests that I can use the ModuleDependency attribute to setup this kind of link, however it does not seem to be working.

So I have my storage class as:

```
[Module(ModuleName = "StorageModule")]
public class UserStorageModule : IModule
{
   //code here
}
```

And then the consumer as:

```
[ModuleDependency("StorageModule")]
public class EntryModule : IModule
{
   //code here
}
```

However the EntryModule.Initialize() method is still called first. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921124(v=pandp.20).aspx seems to indicate this can be used only with a catalog from a directroy, is that what you are using? You probably also should add a `Module( ModuleName = EntryModule )`.

Comment: Thanks @stijn, I am not loading from directory so that would explain why it was not making any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lesson in giving up the search too soon. Some more searching revealed this solution

[How to control the order of module initialization in Prism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296642/how-to-control-the-order-of-module-initialization-in-prism)

Which seems to solve my problem nicely.